# iOS 7.0 and up: Image size for 3.5 retina iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm doing walkthrough module and have issues with showing custom images in an imageView while sliding.

I have prepared images for for iPhone 5+ and special sized set for iPhone4.

```
5 and 6 - image@2x = 640 x 1136
6+      - image@3x = 1242 x 2208
4       - image3_5@2x = 640 x 960
```

It works flawless in 5,6 and 6++, but not on iPhone4 image looks blur and doesn't fit.

[image] [image]

I store images in `Images.xcassets` folder.

for 5 and up

[image]

for 4

[image]

What's wrong with it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is set correctly with the cassettes, which it seems as though they are, you should just confirm that the images you added are actually the sizes you claim.  Then next thing that would be causing issues is the imageView itself and how it is sizing itself with the screen.

Things you can do to figure out what the issue is:

1. Set a breakpoint in the code where the image is allocated into memory.  Print out the size properties of the image to make sure they match what you expect.
2. Set a breakpoint in the code in viewDidAppear and print out the frame of the imageView, my bet is that it is not the correct size on the given device and is causing the image inside of it to stretch which would cause this blur that you are talking about.

Let me know what you find.

Comment: Ok, after NSLogging the part you mentioned: imageView: 568 x 320, image 240 x 160. So, looks like image view doesn't resize itself when running on iphone4...

Comment: also, the image gets wrong size for some unknown reason

Comment: @NCF check the actual image which you added to cassettes and see its size.  Right click on the image in cassettes and hit show in finder.  The right click on that image in finder and hit get info to view its size.

Comment: 640 x 1136 I checked it.

Comment: I thought you said it was supposed to be 640 x 960?  Unless you checked a different one, I am looking for the size of the one which is giving you problems, the iPhone4 @2x one.